# convert special characters in javascript file

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, dynamics-crm, jscript, docxtemplater

I am using DocXTemplater for exporting table to word document

In the js file, there is a module with special characters, and CRM is not allowing me to create a file with these special characters. I tried removing the variables with special character, but the functionality is not working without them. How can I include the below binary special characters

```
28: [function(t, e, n) {
        "use strict";
        n.LOCAL_FILE_HEADER = "PK",
        n.CENTRAL_FILE_HEADER = "PK",
        n.CENTRAL_DIRECTORY_END = "PK",
        n.ZIP64_CENTRAL_DIRECTORY_LOCATOR = "PK",
        n.ZIP64_CENTRAL_DIRECTORY_END = "PK",
        n.DATA_DESCRIPTOR = "PK\b"
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is crm not allowing you to do? Did you try adding the characters in these two ways?

```
[function(t, e, n) {
    "use strict";
    n.LOCAL_FILE_HEADER = "PK" + String.fromCharCode(3),
    n.CENTRAL_FILE_HEADER = "PK\x03",
}
```

If this works you can get a list of the characters you are seeing and transform them into unicode codes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: Yes, when I tried to replace ENQ with \x05, it didn't work
I did not try the string.fromCharCode way though, I am not familiar with that

Comment: @vignesh you could also try the unicode representations. For example, `"PKETXEOT"` would be `"PK\u0003\u0004"`

Comment: I uploaded the entire file
The editor did not allow me to save with special characters